# How to bind @package fields in BaiDuMaps for iOS using btouch?

Tags: objective-c, ios, binding, xamarin.ios, package

```
import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

import"BMKAnnotation.h"

@interface BMKShape : NSObject <BMKAnnotation> {
@package
    NSString *_title;
    NSString *_subtitle;
}
```

I don’t convert the @package to .NET code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple ObjectiveC documentation about [**@package**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/RN-ObjectiveC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004309-CH1-DontLinkElementID_7) states:

```
@package is a new instance variable protection class, like @public and @protected.
@package instance variables behave as follows:

    @public in 32-bit;

    @public in 64-bit, inside the framework that defined the class;

    @private in 64-bit, outside the framework that defined the class.
```

In .NET world that's **public** visibility in 32bits and **internal** visibility in 64bits. 
Since iOS is 32bits you should bind those as **@public** fields (or not bind them at all since they are likely something that is not meant to be used outside of the provided package).